# Merge sort code in python - recursive fuction call

Tags: python, function, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to understand the below python code for merge sort.

The function `mergeSort` is not returning any value nor are we storing the sorted list to `lefthalf` variable. So how is the value of variable `lefthalf`  changed { for eg to [26,54] } after the function is called.

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    print("Splitting ",alist)
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        print("Before left call------>",lefthalf)
        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        print("after left call------>",lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print("Merging ",alist)

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

**Output :**

```
Splitting  [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
Before left call------> [54, 26, 93, 17]
Splitting  [54, 26, 93, 17]
Before left call------> [54, 26]
Splitting  [54, 26]
Before left call------> [54]
Splitting  [54]
Merging  [54]
after left call------> [54]
Splitting  [26]
Merging  [26]
Merging  [26, 54]
after left call------> [26, 54]
Splitting  [93, 17]
Before left call------> [93]
Splitting  [93]
Merging  [93]
after left call------> [93]
Splitting  [17]
Merging  [17]
Merging  [17, 93]
```

...
... and so on till its a sorted list.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simple answer is - Lists are mutable in Python. Which means that when you are passing list to a method, method can change the list without need to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

The array contents are written back to `alist` towards the end of the function, and `alist` *is* `lefthalf` in the level above.

I found this really confusing when I switched from C to Python, but in Python, everything is a reference to an object, <s>and so all function calls are effectively [pass-by-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)).</s>

Comment: No, function calls are not pass by reference. If they were, assignment to variables passed in would be seen by the caller.

Comment: More like "reference-by-value" but yeah, it makes sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True, it's more like everything is a pointer/handle. Thanks for the correction, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in `lefthalf = alist[:mid]` and `righthalf = alist[mid:]`. It created two new lists: lefthalf and rightlhalf, they are copies of the left half integers and right half integers in alist. When you update these list, alist doesn't change. You can test it with this code:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a = x[:2]
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> b = x[2:]
>>> b
[3, 4]
>>> a[1] = 10
>>> a
[1, 10]
>>> b
[3, 4]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Secondly, During the merge process, alist values are **mutated in place**. E.g. when alist is [54, 26], lefthalf is [54], righthalf is [26], and merge will update alist to [26, 54]. That's why lefthalf is changed to [26, 54] when calling `mergeSort(lefthalf)`.

Lastly, when it calls `megeSort(lefthalf)` and `mergeSort(righthalf)`, it actually updates lefthalf and righthalft because of pass by reference. This can be tested with the code:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> def update(x):
...     x[0] = 100
...
>>> update(l)
>>> l
[100, 2, 3]
```

So in summary, the whole process is for given alist, it created two new lists: lefthalf and righthalf. And after sorting lefthalf and righthalf, alist is updated by merging lefthalf and righthalf. Doing this process recursively will sort alist.

Let me know if it's clear now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Haojin. Answer of @GSazheniuk was what i was looking for.